# I have created a desktop to run a python script but it does not seem to run the file

Tags: python, linux, xdgutils

I am trying to create a desktop file to launch a python script by clicking an icon on my desktop but without much success. With terminal as "true" in the file I very briefly see a terminal open and then close but with terminal as "false" nothing at all. I have checked that the file is executable and can indeed run it from the Linux terminal. The file is in a folder on the desktop as is the .png image file for the desktop icon which registers correctly. I am using Linux Mint 21.2 and python 3.10.12. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=bar till start

Icon=/home/chris/Desktop/start.png

Exec=python3 /home/chris/Desktop/BarTill/barTill05.py

Comment=comment

Terminal=false

Type=Application

Categories=None;
```

Comment: Try setting your terminal to stay open when the command exits. Then you can read the error message or any other output.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The terminal window closes before I have time to read anything clearly, I think it shows only one line?

Comment: Thank you for the tip on where to place the question, I was not sure where to put it, I'll try in the headings you suggest.